# Entity Framework Core using enum as FK

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to have a relation between these 2 classes using an enum. However after i create database with migration, 2 foreign keys are created. Why is it creating it twice?

```
InterventionStateId
InterventionStateId1
```

here is code

on context class

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Intervention>()
          .Property(i => i.InterventionStateId)
          .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Intervention>()
           .HasOne(i => i.InterventionState)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(i => i.InterventionStateId);
```

and the entities

```
public class Intervention
{
    public Intervention()
    {
        InterventionStateId = InterventionStates.PendingValidation;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public InterventionStates InterventionStateId { get; set; }
    public InterventionState InterventionState { get; set; }
}


public enum InterventionStates
{
    PendingValidation = 1,
    PendingStatus = 2,
    Closed = 3
}

[Table("hInterventionStates")]
public class InterventionState
{
    [Key]
    public InterventionStates Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Intervention> Interventions { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Is there any point at all in the `InterventionStates` table? Surely a `context.Interventions.Where(i => i.InterventionStates.Equals(//state));` would do the same thing?

Comment: the point is to be able to query it directly in SQL Server

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Interventions WHERE InterventionStateId = //whatever you want` Still no need for the `InterventionStates` table

Comment: I'll need to join to get what the actual Id means, some of my team won't be able to check the code, they won't know what the integer value means

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` should be unique to every row. The approach you're looking for won't work. Use @BarryO'Kane 's suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments I would model the entities like so

```
public class Intervention
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int InterventionStateId { get; set; }
    public virtual InterventionState InterventionState { get; set; }
}

public class InterventionState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Intervention> Interventions { get; set; }

}
```

Adding enums to the mix avails nothing here, as you either have to store them in the db as strings in order to get the name as you mentioned, or store the int value, which you then have to proceed to lookup.

You can add the unique constraint to the `Name` of the Intervention state

```
modelBuilder<InterventionState>()
    .HasIndex(e => e.Name)
    .IsUnique();
```

but really no more configuration than this is needed.

Comment: the primary key still needs to be of type `InterventionStates` though

Comment: It really doesn't. Using an enum as a primary key is a bad idea. Either store the field just as a property on the `Interventions` table and reference it or follow the approach I've suggested. As I said, you're just asking for trouble with no upside by trying to use an `enum` in this scenario.

Comment: it gives me an exception if i try to use the primary key as integer, it says it's not compatible InterventationStateId and Id on InterventationState. I don't see downside in doing this, using enum i can know what is the name while i'm coding rather than guess what each Id number is or have to look up on database. Also i turned off identity for the lookup table

Comment: You're quite right. I copied the code from the question and forgot to change the FK property to an `int`. Updated. You specifically mentioned the use case where "some of my team won't be able to check the code" so either this is a concern or it isn't. Do you need the name of the `InterventionState` or not?

Comment: Well yes i have been doing this way, the name is just the same as the property in the enum, except it is formatted to show the name to users. It's true i can just keep the mapping in the code but it's easier to keep a look up table in database if someone else needs to query or i cannot access the code.

Comment: I agree that the lookup table is a better solution, but most definitely without an `enum`.